# sbt: conflicting scala binary versions between project and library dependency

Tags: scala, sbt

Disclaimer: new sbt/Scala user

So I have the following `build.sbt` file (`sbt.version=1.1.1`):

```scala
val managedLibs : Setting[_] = libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.11.10" withSources(),
    "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.11.10" withSources(),
    "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.11.10" withSources()
  )

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
    .settings(
      name := "foo",
      organization := "bar",
      scalaVersion := "2.12.4",
      sourcesInBase := false,
      version := "0.1",
      managedLibs
)
```

What I want to do is to use a different compiler version to build my project and a different compiler version from within my project (i.e., as a library). Sbt does not seem to like this and I am getting the following warnings:

```
[warn] Binary version (2.11) for dependency org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.11.10
[warn]  in bar#foo_2.12;0.1 differs from Scala binary version in project (2.12).
[warn] Binary version (2.11) for dependency org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.11.10
[warn]  in bar#foo_2.12;0.1 differs from Scala binary version in project (2.12).
[warn] Binary version (2.11) for dependency org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.10
[warn]  in bar#foo_2.12;0.1 differs from Scala binary version in project (2.12).
[warn] Multiple dependencies with the same organization/name but different versions. To avoid conflict, pick one version:
[warn]  * org.scala-lang:scala-library:(2.12.4, 2.11.10)
```

My program compiles and runs without an issue using scala `2.12.4` (it looks like sbt ignored `2.11.10`) but I am just curious: is it even possible to use different versions in that way ? Is this a hard restriction imposed by sbt ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: I think that's not possible. the closest think I can come up with is cross compilation: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Cross-Build.html

Comment: Why do you want to use diffent versions? I don't think it's possible (or even make sense), so some motivation could be helpful to solve your issue.

Comment: At this point I am only curious if it's possible or a hard restriction by sbt. Not really a blocker for me. Normally it doesn't make sense and I understand your confusion. However, I am using the scala libraries in an unconventional way if you will, where it is conceivable to have different versions but of course not a blocker really (at least for now). What is this unconventional way ? Well, I am building a Scala-based language. A new language that is partly Scala and partly not. So the compiler for this new language doesn't have to match the compiler of its compiler. Hope that help.

Comment: OK, but you should know that Scala 2.11 and 2.12 are _not binary compatible_, so it's not just about sbt, but about Scala compiler itself.